# Why can't I rebind reference variable but I can rebind reference field in struct?

Tags: rust

It seems that I cannot rebind a reference variable in rust

```
let mut arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]; 
                            
let & mut a0 = & mut arr[0];
println!("a0 = {}", a0);    
                            
let mut i = 0;              
a0 = &mut i; // mismatched types: expected integer, found `&mut {integer}`
```

But I can rebind a reference inside `struct`:

```
#[derive(Debug)]   
struct Ref<'a, T> {
    val: &'a T     
}                  

let mut arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

let mut r = Ref {                                          
    val: & arr[0]                                          
};                                                         
println!("r = {:#?}", r);                                  
r.val = & arr[1];
```

Is it true that I cannot rebind a reference variable?

If it can't, then why allow that in `struct`, instead of forbidden it, just like c++?

BTW, is there any standard library type that does the same as `Ref<'a, T>` here in my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write

```
let & mut a0 = & mut arr[0];
```

you use [pattern matching](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-01-all-the-places-for-patterns.html#let-statements) in this let assignement:

`& mut {}` is the pattern. If you replace `{}`, you get `a0` matching `arr[0]`.

The type of `arr[0]` is `usize` so you're defining a variable `a0` of type `usize`.

That's why you can't later put a value of type `&mut usize`.

If you want `a0` to be of type `&mut usize`, do

```
let mut a0 = &mut arr[0];
```

Then you can later do

```
let mut i = 0;              
a0 = &mut i;
```

Comment: Can you explain why `let &mut a0` is pattern matching? I read the link but it doesn't mention anything regarding it.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu When you wrote `let & mut a0 = & mut arr[0];` I guess you meant `let a0: &mut i32 = & mut arr[0];` (you would also have had to insert `mut` before `a0` to allow reassignment afterwards). In Rust you specify the type after `:`. Your formulation is pattern matching because, in a `let` statement, Rust  tries to make both sides of the `=` symbol match. Here `&mut` match perfectly on both sides, then the new name `a0` is associated with `arr[0]` wich is an integer. In the end, `ao` is an integer, not a mutable reference to an integer.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu The link explicitly says that the left-hand side of `let` assignment is a pattern, and goes on to show examples of destructuring using the pattern, such as `let (x, y, z) = (...)`. The `print_coordinates()` example further demonstrates dereferencing using patterns in function parameters.